# AngularJS - passing an interpolated html fragment to a directive attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that receives a json list of items and repeats them in my view. I am using a variation of the bootstrap popover and would like to insert the order ID within the sub template defined my $scope.popover and have it parsed for variables. I read that the square brackets was the way to go but it does not seem to work for me.

```
function ManageOrderCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.subtemplate = '<input class="hidden" value="[order._id]">';

  $http.get('/api/orders').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.orders = data.orders;
    });

  };
}
```

Template (is actually a directive - a variation of the bootstrap popover):

```
<li ng-repeat="order in orders">
   <a href="#" popover="{{ subtemplate }}">{{ order._id }}</a>
<li>
```

Comment: The subtemplate here is treated as a normal string value and scope resolution does not happen. Why do yo want to embed html inside a html attribute `popover`

Comment: There are no errors but the variable order_id doesn't get interpolated. The reason I want to do this is that I need to pass some fairly complex html to the popover attribute - not sure what better way. Was hoping for a simple way rather than writing a directive for it - especially considering the popover is already 2 directives

Comment: why would you ever need to place html in an attribute? Just asking for problems with broken tags when browser parses it

Comment: @charlietfl check out the bootsrap popover - I want to insert html in there. A very common and reasonable request - something that is a snap in jquery - but in jquery I would write my html code in a string and assign it - just trying to find the angular way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
<li ng-repeat="order in orders">
   <a href="#" popover="<input class="hidden" value='{{order._id}}'">{{ order._id }}</a>
<li>
```

Instead of defining the template in controller. You can also create templates using `ngInclude` and include them in the html.

Comment: Yes that's what I have now - but it's so messy - there's a fair amount of html. And ngInclude doesn't seem to get parsed in my case - just prints out: ng-include 'templatename.html'

Comment: I think it doesn't get parsed because the code it's actually going in (in example it's the A tag) is itself a directive